# EF code-first Self-Referencing Many-to-Many update references

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

So I finally wrapped my head around self-referencing many to many relationships in EF code first I think, but now I can into the question about the best way to update these relationships.

Let's say we have this kind of relationship:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
                    .HasMany(c => c.Friends)
                    .WithMany()
```

with the following in the `Contact.cs` class:

```
public virtual iCollection<Contact> Friends {get;set;};
```

In my Contact view, I have a multiselect to choose Friends for the Contact. Then I save by iterating through all the selected ones and running `thisContact.Friends.Add(friend)` and saving the changes.

Then, when you come back to the Contact view, it's easy enough to retrieve the `.Friends` and repopulate the multiselect, but I have been running into problems re-saving the new Friends. What is the best way to go about it? I thought at first to delete all the Friends and then add the new ones from the multiselect, but that doesn't seem very efficient and I was not sure exactly at what point to delete the `.Friends` in relation to saving the `Contact`.

Is there a clean way to go through the new items selected from the multiselect, compare it to what is already in the `thisContact.Friends`, add the new ones, delete the ones that are not there and keep the matching ones?

I hope this makes sense, thank you in advance!

Comment: Just replacing the friends is by far the easiest way. It's not expensive because only very small records are involved (unless there are hundreds of items).

Comment: you mean deleting the friends that exist and then adding new ones?

Comment: Yes. Only records in the junction table get deleted and re-inserted, not the contacts themselves.

Comment: yeah, that's what I was thinking of doing but thought there might be something streamlined. Thanks!

Comment: EF completely lacks support for smoothly updating object graphs. The alternative is something like user1455010's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say you have your domain collection (contact.Friends) and your friends collection returned from the UI (uiFriends).

First you find the friends that have been removed  (psuedo code)

```
var removeTheseFriends = contact.Friends.Except(uiFriends);  // Returns friends that are only in your domain collection
var addTheseFriends = uiFriends.Except(contact.Friends);  // Returns friends only in your UI collection
```

The "Except" method is only good if you are passing complete objects.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.90).aspx

In reality, the UI collection is probably a list of Ids of the contacts in the Friends collection.  In this case, you'd do something like this:

```
var removeTheseFriends = contact.Friends.Where(i => !uiFriends.Contains(i.Id));

// First load the list of friends that correspond to your ui collection Ids
var domainObjectsOfUiFriendsCollection = context.Contacts.Where(i => uiFriends.Contains(i.Id));

// These are now domain objects, so you can now use the Except functionality
var addTheseFriends = domainObjectsOfUiFriendsCollection.Except(contact.Friends);
```

Then just iterate through your lists and add/remove them as appropriate.

Comment: thanks for the information! I guess I will stay with deleting and then adding them again as I don't think it will be too taxing on the system

Comment: With the above, just delete the ones that need to be removed and add the new ones.  The contacts that don't change don't need to have anything done with them.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am not sure exactly how your last sentence "Then just iterate through your lists and add/remove them as appropriate." would look with the variables you created. Would you mind possibly writing it out for me?

Comment: To remove the "contacts" that were removed in the UI:  foreach(var removeThisObject in removeTheseFriends) { contact.Friends.Remove(removeThisObject) };

Comment: To add new contacts: foreach(var newContactToAdd in addTheseFriends) { contact.Friends.Add(newContactToAdd); }   You'd want to save changes once after doing all your edits so that if there's an error you don't have some changes propagated to the database while leaving some changes undone.